# How pointer of an object datatype remains unchanged?

Tags: javascript

In javascript object is reference type . That means any variable that have an Object assigned to it ,  this variable will only holds the pointer of the memory location of the Object where it placed. But when the value or property of the object is extended then occupying memory will also be extended, So  pointer/variable should must include the start and end point of the memory, But how it is possible to remaining the pointer unchanged? As the memory location is extended . Can anyone explain it clearly?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow you to use pointers/references and you certainly can't do memory management in JavaScript, either...

Comment: "*pointer/variable should must include the start and end point of the memory*" - what makes you think that? Even if the object memory size would be dynamic, a length-prefixed block of memory would achieve that just fine, and the pointer doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Java Script maintains some necessary meta data about (and function for) each object, which are not directly accessible via the programming language. The ECMAScript Specification calls these ["internal methods" and "internal slots"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots). So an object reference is really identifying a "container" having all that information. Properties can be added to and deleted from an object, data types of properties may change: what was first a number, may change to yet another object reference. Properties may be iterable or not, overwritable or not, ...etc. Information about these properties, their sizes and data types is managed in that container. The container itself however maintains its unique reference all that time.

Again, the details about this memory organisation are mostly hidden from the programming language, which makes it quite different from lower level languages such as C: there is in JavaScript an extra, almost invisible, layer of meta information which allows for these dynamic changes.

Comment: Awesome clarification. Many Thanks.

Comment: @NurulHasan don't forget to accept the answer if it is indeed what you were looking for.